# GPFS to HDFS Migration

Tags: hadoop, migration, hdfs, bigdata

I have an IBM's BigInsight Cluster where I have ~5k Hive tables and other HBASE data along with some Big SQL Tables. All the data files are in different format i.e. Text, Avro, bz2 etc.
Now to migrate from BigInsight to HDP(Hortonworks Data Platform) I need to understand how we can move data from GPFS to HDFS.

1. Can you please explain what are the architectural differences between GPFS and HDFS. Is for both Namenode will work similarly. What are the changes in Namespace. Copying Namespace wont work.
2. How to access GPFS from other Hadoop Cluster - simply distcp will work?
3. What are the challenges we can face at the time of migration.

I have some options:

- nfs gateway
- distscp
- httpfs
- WebHDFS REST API
- SCP - Secure copy

**My only concern is which one from all these options can work for both GPFS and HDFS. If these are not tested for my scenario, what are the other alternative option I should opt.**

Please suggest for any solution, what are the other things I need to take care.

Thanks.
Regards,
Pardeep Sharma.